# Organ donation from a non-Muslim to a Muslim

Tags: sharia, non-muslim, medical

I was reading [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8010/what-does-islam-say-about-organ-donation) question about the permissibility of Organ donation in Islam. The answer is very detailed and helpful. So it got me thinking about whether a non-Muslim, say a Hindu or a Jew, can donate an organ to a Muslim.

Does the faith of the donor makes any difference in the permissibility of the donation/transplant?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A non-Muslim can donate an organ to a Muslim.
Pay attention some of non-Muslims are kafir and they are unclean (najis), in this situation donation is allowed,too If the life of Muslim be in danger.

When the organ is exited from non-Muslim 's body, It becomes clean and can transplanted to Muslim 's body, and while Muslim 's blood circulates in organ, It becomes a part of Muslim 's body.

This organ doesn't need wergild but if it is possible It 's better to get the satisfaction of avenger of blood.([Ayatollah noori hamedani](http://www.noorihamedani.com/fa/lib/view/121/19#index),Q:1006)

Comment: "This oragan doesn't need village but if it is possible It 's better to get the satisfaction of avenger of blood." - What does that mean??

Comment: @beautifulmind I still don't understand what that means

Comment: @Daniel ,it means that you are not forced to pay diyah for that organ and it 's better to take Permission of avenger of blood of organ giver (wali aldam).

Answer (score 0):

No, the faith of the donor doesn't make a difference at all.  There's no evidence to say that a person being a disbeliever is considered "different" in regards to body from a believer.

What differs is the belief system but we all have the same organs.